# how to link multiple auth providers to an account on android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can anyone exactly give example how to merge multiple auth provider in firebase cause in firebase documentation also there is no exact code how to do it..
This is the exact error i m getting..
An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials.  Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase documentation on [Linking Multiple Auth Providers to an Account on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) contains all the relevant code snippets you should need. If you'd like to see the context of that code, clicking the file name under each snippet (for example `MainActivity.java`) takes you to the [repo that has the full working code](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/7d03e65500cd63a26e5bf9b8b6e4d3ab9479806a/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/MainActivity.java#L486-L486).

For an even more complete example, you can have a look at FirebaseUI for Android, which contains a complete UI for most authentication flows and which supports upgrading anonymous accounts through account linking. For example, see this [code for upgrading an anonymous account to an email+password account](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/8bda799672d44fd2994d2498441859fae3ccb530/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/util/data/AuthOperationManager.java#L62).

If you're having a hard time making these work in your own application, please update your question to show what you've already tried.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but repo that has full working code is like this..
                        FirebaseUser currentUser = task.getResult().getUser();
                        // Merge prevUser and currentUser accounts and data
                        // ...
                    }
                });
        // [END auth_link_and_merge]
    }They are not provide exact code how to merge if you can help me with that..so it will be helpful

Comment: These are the two lines in the snippets that you need to use to link: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/8bda799672d44fd2994d2498441859fae3ccb530/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/util/data/AuthOperationManager.java#L62-L63 The FirebaseUI repo is used by thousands of developers to implement auth without writing their own code. If you're having trouble implementing these in your own app, show what you've tried in your question please.

Comment: Sir Thank you again for your response but i want to merge google account to facebook...this code snippets that you give is for merging email and password ..so if you can please tell me how to do that that will be helpful.

Comment: The code for that is in the next method. If you're having a hard time making that work, show in your question what you've tried.